# Separate regex clauses

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pattern-matching

I need to match a string against a list of predefined keywords and capture it in a group, where as there might be an optional character preceding the keyword.

#### Examples

Allowed keywords:

- contains
- startswith
- equals
- endswith

Optional character: !

```
- input value              - comment
contains(field,value)      // OK
startswith(field,value)    // OK
test(field,value)          // NOK (test is not a valid keyword)
equals(field,value)        // OK
!startswith(field,value)   // OK  (optional character ! allowed)
!contains(field,value)     // OK  (optional character ! allowed)
```

#### Regex

I tried with the following regex:

```
(?<action>!?startswith|endswith|contains|equals)\((?<field>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\)
```

I can successfully capture the groups (`action`, `field`, `value`), but the regex allows the optional character only for `startswith`. How can I separate the two rules and still capture the full keyword? Something like `capture=(optional ?)(any of the allowed keywords)`

Comment: Could you provide an example of a string you might be parsing?

Comment: `(?<action>!?(startswith|endswith|contains|equals))\((?<field>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\)`

Comment: @1000000000 In the grey box. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another one. Prevailing thought is to just move `!?` outside the parenths.

`@"(?<!\S)(?<action>!?(?:startswith|endswith|contains|equals))\((?<field>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\)"`

Formatted

```
 (?<! \S )
 (?<action>                    #_(1 start)         
      !?
      (?:
           startswith
        |  endswith
        |  contains
        |  equals 
      )
 )                             #_(1 end)         
 \(
 (?<field> \w+ )               #_(2)         
 ,
 (?<value> \w+ )               #_(3)         
 \)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `!?` outside the capturing group.

```
@"!?\b(?<action>startswith|endswith|contains|equals)\((?<field>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\)"
```

`\b` word boundary after `!?` is a much needed one.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/10)

Comment: The thing is, I need to capture the ! too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture !startswith and !contains, use the following...

```
(?<action>!?(startswith|endswith|contains|equals))\((?<field>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\)
```

Comment: This works, it however results in 4 capture groups instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

`(?<=^|\p{P}|\p{Zs}|\b)(?<action>\!?(?:startswith|endswith|contains|equals))\((?<field>\w+),(?<value>\w+)\)(?=$|\p{P}|\p{Zs}|\b)` ?

You will match almost all possible boundaries + "!?" is used only once inside the `?<action>` group, and your action will hold the method name with or without the `!` symbol.

Here is some code for testing:

```
var MyRegex = new Regex(
      "(?<=^|\\p{P}|\\p{Zs}|\\b)(?<action>\\!?(?:startswith|endswit" +
      "h|contains|equals))\\((?<field>\\w+),(?<value>\\w+)\\)(?=$|\\p" +
      "{P}|\\p{Zs}|\\b)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.Multiline
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
// Capture all Matches in the InputText
var ms = MyRegex.Matches(@"contains(field,value)    OK
startswith(field,value)  OK
test(field,value)        NOK (test is not a valid keyword)
equals(field,value)      OK
!startswith(field,value) OK  (optional character ! allowed)
!contains(field,value)   OK  (optional character ! allowed)");

foreach (var capturedgroup in ms.Cast<Match>().ToList())
{
    var action = capturedgroup.Groups["action"].Value;
    var field = capturedgroup.Groups["field"].Value;
    var value = capturedgroup.Groups["value"].Value;
}
```

Or, in case you have to check the method names as separate strings, use this:

```
var MyRegex = new Regex("(?<action>\\!?(?:startswith|endswith|contains|equals))\\((?<field>\\w+),(?<value>\\w+)\\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var ms = MyRegex.Match(@"!contains(field,value)");
var action = ms.Groups["action"].Value;
var field = ms.Groups["field"].Value;
var value = ms.Groups["value"].Value;
```